# PySocks ошибка использования прокси

Tags: python, socks5

Мне необходимо использовать прокси в telegram - боте. Использую Telethon.

```
TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy).start()
```

В документации написано, что можно использовать прокси библиотекой PySocks, но там дан пример без авторизации.

Пытаюсь использовать так:

```
proxy = (socks.SOCKS5, "217.29.62.231", 34354, True, "VYasd823dsa1", "sgg5dg1d1dfdfa")
```

Но кидает ошибку:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 851, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 497, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self, CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 578, in _SOCKS5_request
    raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error))
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x05: Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 549, in <module>
    create_client("996776912989")
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 186, in create_client
    clients.append(TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy).start())
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 115, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 122, in _start
    await self.connect()
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 349, in connect
    proxy=self._proxy
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 139, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 217, in _connect
    await self._connection.connect(timeout=self._connect_timeout)
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\tcpfull.py", line 18, in connect
    await super().connect(timeout=timeout, ssl=ssl)
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 62, in connect
    loop=self._loop
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 358, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 439, in sock_connect
    return (yield from fut)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 444, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 100, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Git\telegram\env\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 855, in connect
    raise GeneralProxyError("Socket error", error)
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 0x05: Connection refused
```

Как его правильно использовать?

Comment: Очевидно, порт должен быть числом, а не строкой

Comment: @andreymal случайно не тот код скинул, посмотрите еще раз